# gift card - private key - how to redeem?

Tags: myetherwallet, private-key

Someone gave me a gift card with an address - 0X ... - and a private key - list of words.

I have used various wallets but I am unsure what I an meant to do with this. How from the address alone and the key can I move the money to one of my wallets? I have used myetherwallet before.

Thanks

Comment: Did your friend create the gift card or is there a particular company that made the card? If it's a company, they might have a website that can tell you how to access the account. (Although buying such a gift card seems unsafe.) In any case, you should take the ether associated with the address and move it to an address you generated (in case someone else has a copy of the private key).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this from MyEtherWallet. Please triple check you are on the right site!  Look for the EV-SLL notice:

[image]

From the "Send Ether & Tokens" tab choose "Mnemonic phrase". Type your list of words in there and you ought to be able to access the account.

Answer (score 0):

For those wanting more information about Mnemonics..

These phrases are based on [BIP39](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039.mediawiki). The idea is that a mnemonic is easier to remember than a private key.

A mnemonic **is** your private key. Anyone who has it can access your Ethereum wallet.

You can access your wallet through many products:

- [MyEtherWallet](https://www.myetherwallet.com/)
- [EthTools.com](https://ethtools.com/mainnet/wallet/create/) (my companies product)
- [Jaxx](https://jaxx.io/)

etc

Make sure you only use a product that you trust.